# Python socket.gethostbyname function return an ip address but I am unable to ping it

Tags: python, sockets

I wrote a small script to get the ip address for a list of hostnames. However when I try to ping the ip address I get request time outs. Why can this happen?

```
import csv
import socket

path = 'Clients.csv'

with open(path) as fopen:
    rows = csv.reader(fopen)
    for row in rows:
        try:
            resp = socket.gethostbyname(row[0])
            print(row[0], resp)
        except:
            continue
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is in the question: the DNS server you are requesting knows about the name, so it gives you the matching IP.

It does not mean that the machine that does the ping can actually find a network path to ping the destination. For example, there could be a firewall between the originated server and the pinged server, networks between source and destination are not necessarily routed together, etc.

Timeouts are probably the sign of a blocking firewall.

Comment: the DNS server used will be the DNS server configured on the network interface on the machine from which the script is running from?

Comment: depends on OS. On Linux and on common BSDs it will probably be name servers specified in `/etc/resolv.conf`. More generally on POSIX systems `/etc/nsswitch.conf` dictates where `gethostbyname` will get answers from.